# Rewrite path for a requested image from a HttpModule

Tags: asp.net, iis, system.web

I've developed an IIS HTTP module that does dynamic image resizing. It looks at the incoming URL and performs a regex to determine if the URL is a match for that images that we want to resize, and pulls out the requested image size (thumbnail, large etc). It then checks for a cached version of this particular image size on disk, then either outputs that, or if not found it resizes the source image to the requested size, saves it to disk and then outputs that file.
The crux of the code is here:

```
        context.Response.WriteFile(file);
        context.Response.End();
```

However this always brings back a HTTP status code of 200, and never 304s on subsequent requests. Instead, I thought it would be better to instead just make my module change the "virtual" path of where other HTTP Handlers would see the file request and they can do their own thing, such as caching etc.
I tried using HttpContext.RewritePath() but this caused 500 errors, possibly because of the point below:

My image folder lives outside of the website root directory. I don't want them in web root because somebody could perhaps request the source images. This image resizing system only allows images of a certain maximum size.

Comment: StaticFileHandler requires fixed paths under web site root. That does not look compatible with on-the-fly resizing. Can you add more details?

Comment: @UserControl Added more informatin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try the following options:

1. Create symbolic link under the site's root pointing to a folder where your images are stored (the simplest way).
2. Manually check for `If-Modified-Since` request header and return 304 if needed.
3. Leave servicing static content to `StaticFileHandler` only and check for 404 error redirecting to resizing url if regex matches.

**EDIT:**
So OK, now I can imaging the following solution:

Let's assume there is a folder for original images and folders for specific sizes somewhere outside the site's folder: `/blabla/origin`, `/blabla/50x50/`, `/blabla/250x250`, etc. We can create symlinks pointing to these folders so IIS can serve them as regular static content. The pages can assume there are always images of all sizes present. If this is not the case (new image appeared in `/blabla/origin/foo.jpg`) and request comes for `/50x50/foo.jpg` the site returns 404 status code that we can intercept in `Page_Error()` event handler. Within the handler we can check if the request came for a resized images and redirect to another url (handler) that will resize `/origin/foo.jpg` to `/50x50` and `/250x250` folder and either return resized content immediately or redirect back to original url.

Comment: Sounds good, but how do I tell the StaticFileHandler to server another image instead of the requested one? e.g. request comes in for /products/image/12345-large.jpg but I want to display an image from /products/images/cached/12345/large.jpg

Comment: Almost there. I've setup my symolic link inside my website's root directory to the product directory, and am using HttpContext.RewritePath to output this location. I'm getting a 404 error now, however if I copy & paste the "physical path" to Windows Explorer, I actually navigate to the folder, so it exists on disk and hasn't been mistyped.

Comment: Solved - the symbolic link was to a shared network drive, and that couldn't be accessed by IIS. I tested with a symbolic link to a local directory and that readable. This is working great now - my images are bringing back 304s and all the correct response HTTP headers. Thanks.